# How to make custom llvm pass for changing control flow?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I want to make a pass that changing control flow.

The pass should change the `if` condition.

Let's assume the original code is like below.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (atoi(argv[1]) % 2 == 0)
    printf("even\n");
  else
    printf("odd\n");

  return 0;
}
```

After apply my pass the code should be changed to below. (Not mean that changing the **source** code, but **IR** code in real.)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (atoi(argv[1]) % 2 == 1)    //the condition of if statement is changed to 1
    printf("even\n");
  else
    printf("odd\n");

  return 0;
}
```

this is just a toy example of what I really want to do but I have difficulties about

1. **finding appropriate instructions** want to change
2. and changing the control flows.

Comment: To change instructions, you should manipulate the module on bitcode level, delete the old instruction and use IRBuilder to add new instructions. You could check here http://llvm.org/docs/ProgrammersManual.html#making-simple-changes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with compiling this code to LLVM IR to get an idea what you are going to work on:

```
 # clang -S -emit-llvm -o - main.c
```

Then you will see that you are interested in `icmp` instruction and its operands. In your pass, iterate over all instructions in a `Function`, search for `ICmpInst` using `isa<>` or `dyn_cast<>`, then analyze its operands with `getOperand()` method and replace `ConstantInt` operand with `0` value by the same `ConstantInt` with `1` value.

Comment: really appreciate about your answer! much better understanding about pass.